# Is there a name for $f(M, x) = x^\top M x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I often encounter things of the form $x^\top M x$, where $M$ is symmetric positive (semi-)definite. Is there a term for that? I know related terms:

- We can say $M$ is a [bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form), $M(x,y) = x^\top M y$ with an induced norm, $|\!|x|\!|_M := \sqrt{x^\top M x}$, so I could call $x^\top M x = \!\|x|\!|_M^2$ "the squared norm of $x$ with respect to $M$ I guess?
- This is related to [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance), although that's very particular to statistics.
- This is related to the idea of a [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) where $M$ is the metric tensor and .
- It looks like this can be called a ["change of basis" of a bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#The_matrix_of_a_bilinear_form).

So: In general, is there a name for $f(M, x) = x^\top M x$? There must be, right?

Comment: Change of basis would replace $M$ by $A^\top M A$ for a square matrix $A$, whereas I assume you mean $x$ to be a vector.

Comment: I was picturing $x$ being either a matrix or a vector. It seems like the common nomenclature makes a distinction when I was ideally looking for a term that doesn't make that distinction.

Comment: Yes, there is a name: quadratic form, and I think this question is not appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can say that $x^\top M x$ is the quadratic form associated to $M$.

Comment: Would you say that even if $x$ is a matrix?

Comment: No, I don't think I would.  Didn't realize you were permitting $x$ to be a matrix!

Comment: On the other hand, $A^\top A$ is a quadratic form, right? It is "a thing squared".

Comment: Read the definition of real quadratic form here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Real_quadratic_forms

Comment: I think "quadratic form" is it. So when writing code, would `M.quadraticForm(x)` then be reasonable? Part of the confusion for me of naming $f(M, x)$ (as a binary function) is I don't see a clear ordering, and clearly $M^\top x M$ is different from $x^\top M x$.

Comment: Upon further consideration, from a programming standpoint, I think the binary version should take $M$ first then $x$, since $M$ is more important – it's the quadratic form associated to $M$. That is: `template <typename Matrix, typename VecOrMatrix> auto quadraticForm(Matrix&& M, VecOrMatrix&& v) { return v.transpose() * M * v; }` Like this: https://godbolt.org/z/dSBTXW